Create date_range with predefined number of periods in polars
When I create a date range in pandas, I often use the periods argument. Something like this:
pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=8)

DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-04',
               '2018-01-05', '2018-01-06', '2018-01-07', '2018-01-08'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')

What would be the equivalent way in polars? I am missing the periods input parameter in pl.date_range.
Having said that, there's probably an easy and clever solution ;-)

Adding a periods argument has been an open feature request for a while now.
Until the request has been implemented, you can make start an expression and create end by offsetting start by the desired number of periods (using pl.Expr.dt.offset_by).
start = pl.lit("1/1/2018").str.to_date()
pl.date_range(start=start, end=start.dt.offset_by("7d"), eager=True)

shape: (8,)
Series: 'literal' [date]
[
    2018-01-01
    2018-01-02
    2018-01-03
    2018-01-04
    2018-01-05
    2018-01-06
    2018-01-07
    2018-01-08
]


Is it possible to just get business days?

@Andi Not purely within pl.date_range. Still, you could filter the resulting series dates as follows: dates.filter(dates.dt.weekday() <= 5).

Thanks for this suggestion! Unfortunately, this won't take into account any bank holidays. However, maybe it's possible to utilize the holidays library into the filter context? Bank holidays are country specific anyway.

@Andi That should work. You can combine a filter with pl.business_day_count and holidays from the holidays library.
